# Can't retrieve data from list<keyvaluepair>

Tags: c#

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, String> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();

myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, SelectList>("theKey", "FIND THIS!"));
```

How can I retrieve `"FIND THIS!"` from `myList` knowing only `theKey`? This attempt is not working.

```
String find = myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey");
```

Coming from other languages, I've always had the possibility to search in big associative arrays and retrieve values like this: `array[key] = value;`

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Your declaration is wrong. `List<KeyValuePair<String, SelectList> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, SelectList>>();
`

Comment: wouldn't a dictionary be better?

Comment: ops! corrected the question, thanks!

Comment: *"Coming from other languages, I've always had the possibility to search in big associative arrays"* => `Dictionary` is an associative array; `List` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `List<KeyValuePair>`, use `Dictionary<string, SelectList>` and then you can access it like :

```
array[key] = value;
```

You can use Dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<String, SelectList> dictionary= new Dictionary<String, SelectList>();
dictionary.Add("theKey", "FIND THIS!");

Console.WriteLine(dictionary["theKey"]);
```

Comment: Cool! This is working! Thanks! I've never have to write a model for every stupid thing from now...

Comment: @Saturnix, you are welcome, just remember that keys in the dictionary should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict.Add("theKey", "FIND THIS!");
```

now you can find the value via the key:

```
string value = myDict["theKey"];
```

You can change the value   in this way:

```
myDict["theKey"] = "new value";  // works even if the key doesn't exist, then it will be added
```

Note that the keys must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

How about Dictionary ?

```
IDictionary<String, String> foo = new Dictionary<String, String>();
foo.Add("hello","world");
```

now you can use []

```
foo["Hello"];
```

however with C#

```
string value;

if(foo.TryGetValue("Hello" , out value)){
   // now you have value
}
```

is much more preferable and safer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers you should use a Dictionary for this.

However, the reason your line `String find = myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey");` is not working is that `myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey");` will return a `KeyValuePair`. If you just want the value you could try:

```
String find = myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey").Single().Value;
```

or if you need to check for nulls then maybe:

```
var findKeyValue = myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey").SingleOrDefault();
if(findKeyValue != null)
{
    var find = findKeyValue.Value;
}
```

You can also use the following snippet (in which case you'll either have the value or null)

```
var find = myList.Where(m => m.Key == "theKey").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: you can put a `Select(kvp=>kvp.Value)` before the `SingleOrDefault` to avoid the null check.

Comment: Thanks, added it into the answer :)